# Dynamically generating query using function

Tags: mysql, select, user-defined-functions

I just started learning use defined functions in `MYSQL` and I tried few basic examples, but when I tried a function which returns `varchar`, which actually returns a portion of a `select query`, it gives me something unexpected.

There  are lot of tables in database with columns as `id` and `name`, so whenever people want to fetch `id` for a particular `name` or vice versa they go into the table and manually fetch the data. So I was trying to create a function that would smoothen the process.

This is my function

```
create function getTableDetails(table_name varchar(20), id int(5), name varchar(20)) 
returns varchar(50)
begin
    return " * from " + table_name + " where id = " + id + 
               " or name like '%" + name + "%'";
end
```

As you can see I'm trying to generalize the query for all tables and it returns everything other than the `select` keyword.

Now my query will be like `select getTableDetails('classes', 2, 'a')`

Assuming that the return of the function will fill the rest of the query and give me the table data, but the result set what I'm getting is

```
getTableDetails('classes'; 2; 'a')
2
```

`getTableDetails('classes'; 2; 'a')` is the header.

Where I'm getting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't dynamically generate and execute query like that, from command line. You need to use `preparedstatement` and that too, from stored procedure, e.g.:

```
SET @query = CONCAT('select', getTableDetails('classes', 2, 'a'));

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: what I was guessing was when the select query was executed the function will execute first then the query will execute. Was my assumption write? Can you please explain the flow of that query execution in your answer?

Comment: When `SELECT` query gets called, the function gets executed. However, it results in a query itself and that does not get executed dynamically. So you will end up with a `string` by executing that select query (also, I beileve you should use `CONCAT` instead of `+`). If you want this resultant query to get executed again then you need to use prepared statements. Have a look at MySQL's documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).